# /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) on python:3.7-slim-stretch

Tags: java, docker

Hi i need to build python:3.7-slim-stretch docker image with java

Here my Dockerfile :

```
FROM python:3.7-slim-stretch


# Install OpenJDK-8
RUN apt-get update && \
apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk && \
apt-get install -y ant && \
apt-get clean;

# Fix certificate issues
RUN apt-get update && \
apt-get install ca-certificates-java && \
apt-get clean && \
update-ca-certificates -f;
# Setup JAVA_HOME -- useful for docker commandline
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/
RUN export JAVA_HOME
```

But i'm getting this error when i  build it :

```
...
update-alternatives: error: error creating symbolic link '/usr/share/man/man1/rmid.1.gz.dpkg-tmp': No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package openjdk-8-jre-headless:amd64 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ca-certificates-java:


dpkg: error processing package openjdk-8-jdk:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of openjdk-8-jre:amd64:
 openjdk-8-jre:amd64 depends on openjdk-8-jre-headless (= 8u232-b09-1~deb9u1); however:
  Package openjdk-8-jre-headless:amd64 is not configured yet.

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk && apt-get install -y ant && apt-get clean;' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

add this to your `dockerfile` before insatll :

```
RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/man/man1/
```

you may also remove `RUN export JAVA_HOME` since it has no effect in Dockerfile